# VSTS not building Test.dll in Release

Tags: c#, unit-testing, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.x application with three projects

- App.dll
- App.BL.dll
- App.Tests.dll

The Tests project references the other projects, but is not referenced by the others of course.

I get the error:

### [warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\release*test*.dll,!**\obj**,**\App.Tests.dll.

When VSTS builds the Release version, the agent work folder doesn't contain the App.Tests.dll so the VSTS Test runner doesn't run, there is no dll to run on.

[image]

Here is a picture of the agent build folder. No App.Test.dll

How can I get the agent to build the App.Tests.dll ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .NET Core task with 'test' command instead. It's a simpler way.

[.NET Core task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OwLy.png)